# Left_join retornando dataframe com mais linhas do que o original

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenho um data.frame com dados de censos do IBGE e uma coluna chamada `IND` e tenho um outro data.frame com uma coluna `IND` e outra coluna `NEW_IND`. A coluna `NEW_IND` contém os novos códigos para as indústrias por ano, conforme pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando um `left_join` com a minha base original, que contém 33.523 observações, mas após usar essa função, a base fica com 37.967. Gostaria de entender porque a o `left_join` acrescenta tantas linhas e se há uma forma de não acrescentá-las.

Código que estou usando:

```
teste <- left_join(sample, industry, by = c("YEAR", "IND"))
```

Meu `dput` da amostra:

```
structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(1991L, 1991L, 1980L, 1970L, 
2010L, 2010L, 1991L, 1980L, 1970L, 1991L, 2000L, 1970L, 2010L, 
1991L, 1970L, 1970L, 1960L, 1970L, 2000L, 1980L, 1991L, 1970L, 
2010L, 2010L, 1991L, 1970L, 1960L, 1980L, 1970L, 1980L, 1991L, 
1991L, 2010L, 2000L, 1980L, 1980L, 1991L, 1970L, 1980L, 2000L, 
2000L, 1980L, 1991L, 1960L, 1970L, 1980L, 1960L, 1980L, 1970L, 
1970L), label = "Year", var_desc = "YEAR gives the year in which the census or survey was taken. For samples that span years, the midpoint or first year of the interval is reported."), 
    PERWT = structure(c(8.36, 9.41, 4, 3, 3.49, 9.69, 14.79, 
    4, 4, 4.17, 10.66, 4, 8.65, 4.46, 3, 4, 5, 4, 15.68, 4, 6.29, 
    4, 12.1, 7.97, 5.76, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5.69, 8.24, 3.7, 9.32, 
    4, 5, 12.93, 4, 3, 7.48, 11.59, 5, 1.4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 
    3), label = "Person weight", var_desc = "PERWT indicates the number of persons in the actual population represented by the person in the sample.\n\nFor the samples that are truly weighted (see the comparability discussion), PERWT must be used to yield accurate statistics for the population.\n\nNOTE: PERWT has 2 implied decimal places.  That is, the last two digits of the eight-digit variable are decimal digits, but there is no actual decimal in the data."), 
    IND = c(110, 340, 110, 330, 110, 110, 110, 110, 516, 12, 
    53030, 927, 68000, 200, 122, 122, 326, 414, 55030, 724, 200, 
    110, 87000, 48042, 20, 110, 110, 611, 116, 631, 110, 150, 
    85012, 70002, 251, 20, 110, 110, 25, 36090, 110, 541, 110, 
    110, 341, 110, 110, 525, 110, 118)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`dput` do meu data.frame com o código das indústrias:

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(1970, 2010, 1980, 2010, 2010, 1980, 2010, 
2000, 1991, 1980, 1980, 2010, 1960, 2010, 1980, 2010, 1960, 1991, 
1960, 1991, 1970, 1960, 2010, 1960, 1980, 2010, 1991, 1970, 2010, 
1970, 2010, 2010, 1991, 1991, 2010, 1991, 2000, 2010, 2000, 1970, 
1980, 1960, 1980, 1960, 2010, 2000, 1960, 2010, 1980, 2010), 
    IND = c(119, 25002, 59, 8002, 81020, 462, 10092, 53111, 120, 
    613, 130, 45010, 859, 48071, 250, 81011, 129, 261, 117, 614, 
    303, 123, 86002, 616, 180, 45020, 416, 932, 33001, 0, 20999, 
    85999, 37, 623, 1401, 612, 60999, 2000, 93030, 330, 610, 
    129, 726, 622, 1116, 15041, 0, 7002, 419, 48042), NEW_IND = c(111, 
    311, 129, 251, 752, 452, 335, 513, 312, 722, 313, 129, 851, 
    418, 333, 513, 111, 335, 111, 756, 254, 111, 713, 616, 316, 
    515, 417, 129, 513, 999, 326, 711, 129, 753, 111, 716, 129, 
    111, 129, 334, 717, 129, 851, 622, 111, 335, 999, 251, 421, 
    413)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É difícil saber exatamente o que está acontecendo sem ver seus dados completos. Mas talvez seja o seguinte: Quando você executa `left_join(A, B)`, todas as combinações de correspondências entre `A` e `B` são retornadas. Em outras palavras, novas linhas são adicionadas ao seu novo data frame sempre que houver várias linhas em `B` que correspondem a uma mesma linha em `A`. Por exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)

A <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:4],
                col2 = 1:4)
B <- data.frame(col1 = rep(letters[1:2], 2),
                col3 = 4:1)

left_join(A, B, by = "col1")
```

Seu resultado possui 6 linhas, sendo que `A` possui apenas 4.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 2):

Como indicado na [resposta de ALS.Meyer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513519/117168), se em algum ano um código foi desmenbrado em dois ou mais (algo comum nos sistemas de classificação oficiais), então a união retornará mais linhas do que o original. Pela sua amostra de dados, não é possível saber se é o caso, mas eis um exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)

dados <- data.frame(perwt = 1:4, ind = 101:104)

codigos <- data.frame(ind = c(101, 101:104), new_ind = 200:204)

left_join(dados, codigos, "ind")
#>     perwt ind new_ind
#> 1     1 101     200
#> 2     1 101     201
#> 3     2 102     202
#> 4     3 103     203
#> 5     4 104     204
```

Veja que a linha correspondente a ind == 101 foi duplicada. Se precisa do número exato de linhas do primeiro *data.frame* e não tiver problema em trabalhar com os códigos como *strings* de texto mais tarde, uma opção é usar `nest_join` para agregar os valores duplicados:

```
nest_join(dados, codigos, by = "ind", name = "new_ind")
#>   perwt ind  new_ind
#> 1     1 101 200, 201
#> 2     2 102      202
#> 3     3 103      203
#> 4     4 104      204
```

Ou, usando apenas R base:

```
cod.a <- aggregate(new_ind ~ ind, codigos, paste)

merge(cod.a, dados, by = "ind", all.y = TRUE)
#>   ind  new_ind perwt
#> 1 101 200, 201     1
#> 2 102      202     2
#> 3 103      203     3
#> 4 104      204     4
```